# Сохранение порядка входных и выходных данных при использовании горутин

Tags: golang

Имеется функция, которая выполняет переданные ей функции параллельно, собирает результат и возвращает:

```
func gather(funcs []func() any) []any {
    var res []any
    stream := make(chan any, len(funcs))

    for _, elem := range funcs {
        go func(elem func() any) {
            stream <- elem()
        }(elem)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(funcs); i++ {
        res = append(res, <-stream)
    }
    return res
}
```

В эту функцию отправляются функции считающие квадрат с задержкой:

```
func squared(n int) func() any {
    return func() any {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(n) * 100 * time.Millisecond)
        return n * n
    }
}
```

Из main() они отправляются так:

```
funcs := []func() any{squared(4), squared(3), squared(2)}
nums := gather(funcs)
```

Проблема состоит в том, что в рамках задачи необходимо вернуть результаты ровно в том же порядке, что они были отправлены. Для примера выше правильным выводом будет: [16 9 4], по факту конечно же получаем [4 9 16]. Насколько я понимаю, вызвано это тем, что функции с меньшим входным числом отрабатывают немного быстрее и результат попадает в буферизированный канал раньше.
Я пробовал использовать WaitGroup, например так:

```
func gather(funcs []func() any) []any {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(funcs))
    var res []any
    stream := make(chan any, len(funcs))

    for _, elem := range funcs {
        go func(elem func() any) {
            defer wg.Done()
            stream <- elem()
        }(elem)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    for i := 0; i < len(funcs); i++ {
        res = append(res, <-stream)
    }
    return res
}
```

Пробовал использовать канал завершения <-done.
Все мои попытки либо не приводят к желаемому результату, либо убивают всю идею многопоточности (например, ожидать завершения горутины в каждой итерации цикла).
Что я упускаю? Какой есть метод сохранения порядка вывода?
Я не разбираюсь в JS, но насколько я понимаю в других языках это делается с помощью async/await и например Promise.all (в JS). Как это реализовать в моих условиях на Golang?

Comment: Передавай ожидаемый порядок вместе с рассчитываемым значением в горутину.

Comment: @u_mulder, как Вы предлагаете это сделать? Я ради эксперимента пробовал без цикла друг за другом вызвать горутины передавая туда функции в нужном порядке. Они все равно выстраиваются в порядке завершения, то есть от меньшего к большему.

Comment: Создать структуру где одним полем вызываемая функция, а вторым - ее порядковый номер. Эту структуру передавать в канал.

Comment: @u_mulder, возможно я как-то криво реализовал, но в канал уже должен попасть результат функции (иначе смысл в параллельности?). Я сделал структуру и горутине передавал  индекс: `stream <- elem.id`, а затем выполнение функции `stream <- elem.fn()`. Если потом последовательно прочитать канал, то получаем верную последовательность индексов и всю ту же неверную последовательность результатов: `[0 1 2 4 9 16]`

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/-9sWT5dFkA_2 + `sort.Slice()`

Comment: wg не нужен, потому что вы и так ждете все результаты в `append(res, <-stream)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func gather(funcs []func() any) []any {
    // мы знаем размер массива с функциями, поэтому можем сразу выделить память
    res := make([]any, len(funcs))
    stream := make(chan any, len(funcs))

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(funcs))

    for idx, elem := range funcs {
        idx := idx // нужно сделать копию, иначе все функции будут использовать один и тот же idx
        // этот индекс уже есть порядковый номер вызова
        go func(elem func() any) {
            stream <- elem()
            res[idx] = elem()
            wg.Done()
        }(elem)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return res
}
```

но операции с массивами не потоконебезопасно. но так как мы создали массив определенной длины, и ссылаемся на конкретный индекс, то можно так сделать

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Только не совсем понял зачем при таком подходе канал stream? Убрал его полностью - работоспособность не изменилась. Из-за этого канала время работы в два раза увеличивается (perfomance тесты не проходили).
Помечу Ваш ответ, как решение, а снизу приложу еще варианты с структурой (без прямой записи в срез) и с каналом завершения вместо sync.WaitGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения #1 с использованием структуры и без прямой записи в срез в горутине.

```
func gather(funcs []func() any) []any {
    // результат вызова функции и ее индекс
    type result struct {
        idx int
        val any
    }

    n := len(funcs)

    // запускаем каждую функцию в горутине и отправляем результат в канал
    ready := make(chan result, n)
    for idx, fn := range funcs {
        idx := idx
        fn := fn
        go func() {
            ready <- result{idx, fn()}
        }()
    }

    // забираем результаты из канала и аккумулируем в итоговом срезе
    results := make([]any, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        res := <-ready
        results[res.idx] = res.val
    }
    return results
}
```

Вариант решения #2 с прямым обращением к срезу и использованием закрывающего канала для отслеживания отработки всех запущенных горутин.

```
func gather(funcs []func() any) []any {
    done := make(chan struct{})

    //создаем срез размером по количеству переданных функций
    results := make([]any, len(funcs))

    // запускаем функции в отдельной горутине
    for idx, fn := range funcs {
        idx, fn := idx, fn
        go func() {
            // записываем результат i-й функции в i-ю позицию среза
            results[idx] = fn()
            done <- struct{}{}
        }()
    }

    // дожидаемся, пока отработают все горутины
    for i := 0; i < len(funcs); i++ {
        <-done
    }

    return results
}
```